# Javascript / JQuery Save value to file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few radio buttons in a page and I need to save their values or whatever value is selected to a file.

Here is a sample code:

```
 <input name="select" type="radio" value="a" />
 <input name="select" type="radio" value="b" />
 <input name="select" type="radio" value="c" />
 <input name="select" type="radio" value="d" />
```

Whenever the user selects one I need it saved / appended into a file.

Possible?

UPDATE:

Tried this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {

$("input[name='select']").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("zzz.html", { selectedValue : $(this).val()  }, function(response) {
        // do something with server response
        alert('saved');
    });
});



});
  </script>
```

Result: No Result. Nothing created / Nothing Saved.

Comment: On the server? On the client? Where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the the text to a file on your server, then you can use php.

This example checks to see if a file name has been set, and the text to log has also been set.
It opens the file and appends text to it by specifying "a+".

So visiting

```
http://websitename.com/myfile.php?filename=test.txt&log=string to write
```

Will create and append the text to that file on your server.
If then you want to provide the textfile to the user to download you can just use

```
http://websitename.com/test.txt
```

This code is untested

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["filename"]) == true && isset($_GET["log"]) == true){
    $fp = fopen($_GET["filename"], "a+");

    if($fp !== null){
        fputs($fp, $_GET["log"] . "\r\n");
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
?>
```

jquery get method

```
$.get("myfile.php", { filename: "text.txt", log: "string to write" });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.post('save_values.php', $("form").serialize(), function(){
             alert('saved');
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to save the selected value every time the radio group has been changed:

```
$("input[name='select']").change(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post("foo.html", { selectedValue : $(this).val()  }, function(response) {
        // do something with server response
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is on server you can submit to a servlet and open a file and write on the file.

if it is in client side you can try using this jQuery plugin http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html and do that...