# How to get dynamically created textbox value in jquery or javascript

Tags: jquery

```
 var max_fields = 9;
 var $setting = $("#settingA");
//var $maincontent = $("#mainContent");

// Add html controls
for (var i = 1; i < max_fields; i++) {    
    var checkedElements = [];       
    $setting.append("<span style='margin:10px; line-height:2;'><label style='margin-right:10px;'>Channel " + i + "</label><input type='text' name='product_" + i + "' id='product_" + i + "'/></span>");
    checkedElements.push($('input[name="product_' + i + '"]').val());   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

in HTML:-

```
<input type='text' class='product' name='product_" + i + "' id='product_" + i + "'/>
```

and in jQuery :-

```
 $('.product').each(function() {
           var product =  $(this).val();
           alert(product);
         });
```

Comment: How to save this value to channelSettings.txt file

Comment: How to save this value to channelSettings.txt file onclcik of button

Comment: How save this input value to channelSettings.txt file. Already existing txt file

Comment: trying to update answer but some errors coming while updating

Comment: meanwhile see this http://jquery.tiddlywiki.org/twFile.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964059/javascript-jquery-save-value-to-file

Answer (score 1):

Try like this using starts with selector...

```
$("input[name^='product_']").each(function() {
       var textVal =  $(this).val();
       alert(textVal);
     });
```

Comment: input[name^='product_'] it's showing input is not aaviable

Comment: Surely it will work. Receiving any console error from your side?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$('input[name="product_' + i + '"]').val()
```

try:

```
$('body').find('input[name="product_' + i + '"]').val()
```

Comment: How to get dynamic created text box value in jquery or javascript onclick of button i want value

Comment: @Chinnu Kar: Why did you repeat your question title?